# Missing makecert.exe

Tags: makecert

For some reason I am missing makecert.exe on my system. I searched the whole hard drive and it's not there. In particular, it's not in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin where I believe it's supposed to be. I haven't found any articles on this topic on the Internet. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 19):

makecert.exe is also installed as part of Windows SDKs. For example it is available under \Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin for the Windows 7.0A SDK.

Answer (score 17):

Just to note this as to save you an hour or so of frustration. In Windows 8 SDK, the path is: \Program Files (x86)\Window Kits\8.0\bin\x64\makecert.exe. Note that my machine is 64-bit, so replace the folder names with the corresponding 32-bit version if it happens to be your machine. I was looking at the "\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs" folder, as I thought the folder structure of Windows 7 SDK is similar to Windows 8 SDK. How wrong I was.

Comment: Found it here on Windows 10 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64

Answer (score 9):

I was tasked with deploying `Azure Recovery Services` and as such `makecert.exe` was required on all VMs.

The following worked for me:

---

> ## Azure VM `Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacentre`:
>
> - Download Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4
>     http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279
> - Select .net Framework TOOLS only.
> - Note `makecert.exe` installed to:
>
>   ```
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\x64
>   ```
> - use the following to create the certificate using Powershell:
>
>   ```
>    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\x64\makecert.exe" -r -pe -n CN=CertificateName -ss my -sr localmachine -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -len 2048 -e 01/09/2017 machinename.cer
>   ```

---

> ## Azure VM `Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacentre`:
>
> - Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1
>     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx
> - downloaded all
> - installed these 2 components only:
>
>   - windows software development kit
>   - net framework 4.5.1 software development kit
> - Note `makecert.exe` installed to:
>
>   ```
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin
>   ```
> - use the following to create the certificate using Powershell:
>
>   ```
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Bin\x64\makecert.exe" -r -pe -n CN=CertificateName -ss my -sr localmachine -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -len 2048 -e 01/09/2017 machinename.cer
>   ```

---

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: It works for me. Important to only select the .Net tools that a small package.

Answer (score 4):

here is a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/534fd127-93b5-4f81-b61c-c3f3325d8787) with many other locations on where the exe can be.

Comment: I appreciate the link. Again, it's not in any of those locations but I found it following one of the links on that thread. Still surprised that it's missing. It may have been wiped out after I uninstalled VS2005, but then I would expect to see morepeople with the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the `MakeCert.exe` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Note  MakeCert is deprecated. To create self-signed certificates, use
>   the Powershell Cmdlet New-SelfSignedCertificate.

You should use the new [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate) power shell cmlet.