# Where can I find makecert.exe? Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, makecert

Attempting to use a [makecert UI tool](http://makecertui.codeplex.com/) to make it easier to generate a self-signed code certificates I'm trying to find the DIR location of makecert.exe

I followed [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows) and all the command line switches worked without error. - However when attempting to use the UI tool I received the error:

[image]

So I assumed that I would need to place the tool in the same directory as the makecert.exe and pvk2pfx.exe

Here are the places I've looked:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin (empty)
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\SDK\v3.5\Bin
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 (no relevant folders)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Found it: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64`

or for Visual Studio 2013: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64`

Comment: For Visual Studio 2013 you can find it under C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64

Comment: On Visual Studio 2015 you have to install the Windows 10 SDK to have the file "makecert.exe" installed. There is a solution here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772109/makecert-missing-from-windows-10-and-visual-studio-2015-install

Comment: I accidently down-voted this question some time ago but thought I'd add a comment stating this in case anyone wonders why I did, it just didn't get reversed but agree with the answer, so please ignore the down vote!

Answer (score 24):

[Makecert has been deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/seccrypto/makecert), you can find a PowerShell script that does the same on TechNet: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6

Comment: That is actually a user-submitted gallery script one has to download. You can find the official built-in cmdlet here: https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate

Answer (score 1):

Can't find it on my 2012 or 2013 versions, but 2008 has it under

\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools

\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin

\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\Bin

Guessing it was removed?

Comment: [Also, related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610693/missing-makecert-exe?rq=1)

Comment: @SamuelNicholson Well if it works via command line, why not just type `where makecert` and see what path it gives you? On my machine, it returned "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\makecert.exe"

Comment: In Command Prompt execute `where /R C:\ makecert`. Thanks @Dan for the hint!

Comment: @BartVerkoeijen You don't want to use `/R` in this case, because you may find things which are not in your PATH variable. By default, `where` will search your current directory and all directories defined in your environment PATH variable. Since he can execute the command, it must be in one of those places.

Comment: @Dan To add it to the path, first you need to find it.

Comment: @PaulGeorge It's likely already in your PATH, without you even realizing it. That said, yes, you would need to use /R if for some reason your environment variables have been modified such that `makecert` cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2017 , Windows 10 found it in the following locations:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86`
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64`