# Makecert missing from Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 install?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, makecert

I did a clean install of windows 10 and visual studio 2015 and did not find makecert.exe anywhere. Does some other software need to be installed to get this program back?

I looked in all the folders under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\\" and did not see it in any.

I also opened the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" and tried running "makecert" but it was not found.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Install the [Windows SDK for Windows 10](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk). If you still can't find it, try the [Windows Driver kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx).

[image]

Comment: Installing the windows 10 SDK worked.  I thought the visual studio 2015 install included the SDK, but maybe not all the components.

Comment: Since Win8, Microsoft moved tools from VS to the SDK.

Comment: come on microsoft, it is just an .exe, do we really have to download and install the whole SDK.

Comment: @matthewbaskey submit the request to include the exe in VS again as feedback on connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/

Comment: It's a 69kb standalone .exe file... I can't begin to imagine why MS refuses to offer this as a standalone download, and instead forces me to install 2.5GB of SDK that I have no intention of using. Sheesh...

Comment: To install only makecert, the "Windows SDK" alone should be selected. Please refer: 

http://www.virtues.it/2015/08/howto-create-selfsigned-certificates-with-makecert/

Answer (score 43):

As ShaneH answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323550/1647464) `makecert.exe` has been deprecated, and we should use powershell commandlet New-SelfSignedCertificate.

> New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=Test Code Signing" -Type CodeSigningCert -KeySpec "Signature" -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature" -FriendlyName "Test Code Signing" -NotAfter (get-date).AddYears(5)

---

For older versions of PS, one can get this script from TechNet:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6

To make my answer full, below is brief explanation how to use the TechNet script:

1. Navigate to link above and download New-SelfSignedCertificateEx.zip file
2. Unzip it somewhere
3. Run PowerShell console and navigate to location with new file
4. Run command .\New-SelfSignedCertificateEx to call function. Remember to
   append necessary parameters.

> .\New-SelfsignedCertificateEx -Subject "CN=Test Code Signing" -EKU
>   "Code  Signing" -KeySpec "Signature" -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature"
>   -FriendlyName "Test code signing" -NotAfter [datetime]::now.AddYears(5)

Two additional notes if you are having problem with this tool.

1. If PowerShell moans that scripts are disabled, run console as administrator and call this: `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted`
2. If PowerShell still refuses to run it, make sure you've **prepended** `.\` (dot-slash) before the name of the file, as this is necessary.

Comment: How would I accomplish this with Powershell? https://joekiller.com/2012/04/03/creating-a-x-509-or-signing-certificate-for-aws-ec2-using-powershell-and-windows-sdk/ I couldn't find ANY info.

Comment: Everything is in the link in my comment. Download NewSelfSignedCertificateEx.zip, and then run PowerShell command: New-SelfsignedCertificateEx -Subject "CN=Test Code Signing" -EKU "Code Signing" -KeySpec "Signature" ` 
-KeyUsage "DigitalSignature" -FriendlyName "Test code signing" -NotAfter [datetime]::now.AddYears(5)

Comment: Just a quick note: I could not get `.\New-SelfsignedCertificateEx` to work (no error, no certificate) until I ran `Import-Module .\New-SelfSignedCertificateEx.ps1`. After that I could use `New-SelfsignedCertificateEx` (without the leading ".\") and the script worked fine.

Comment: It works for me in this order: 1. Run `Windows Powershell` as `Administrator` -> 2. Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted` -> 3. Run `New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=Test Code Signing" -Type CodeSigningCert -KeySpec "Signature" -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature" -FriendlyName "Test Code Signing" -NotAfter (get-date).AddYears(5)`

Answer (score 5):

A quick search of my C: found that makecert.exe seems to be distributed with [Fiddler 2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2` folder. This is a much smaller download than the full Windows SDK.

For the record I have version 4.6.20171.26113 of Fiddler 2.

Comment: Still works in Fiddler4: "C:\Users\<youruser>\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler\makecert.exe"

Answer (score 3):

After downloading the Windows SDK for Windows, to install the "makecert.exe" you only have to check the "Windows Software Development Kit".

[image]

Comment: This checkbox is not present in the Windows SDK for Windows 10.