# How to install makecert in windows server 2012 R2 running win 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, makecert

i need makecert.exe in our windows server 2012 R2 production machine (win 10).

i read a lot of post and guides that directs me to install the windows SDK.

[Makecert missing from Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772109/makecert-missing-from-windows-10-and-visual-studio-2015-install)

[Missing makecert.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610693/missing-makecert-exe)

http://www.virtues.it/2015/08/howto-create-selfsigned-certificates-with-makecert/

the only problem is that when i install the SDK i still can't see the makecer.exe in any of the suggested path (windows search was no luck either)

i know that i can install visual studio to get the makecert but it seems stupid to install 8GB for this little tool. and this is a production machine - VS is a big no no!

what are my options?

any help would be greatly appreciated

p.s.  - i know makecert is deprecated but i still need to use it until we'll integrant to the Self-signed certificate generator (PowerShell)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need for a staging environment, so I generated the certs in a development box (where VS and the `makecert` tool is installed), exported them, and then imported into the server.

May be important to note that you should not use a self-signed cert in a production environment for security reasons, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Having said that, below are the steps I followed:

- Generate the Root CA and site certificates using the `makecert` tool in the dev box.
- Enter to Window's "Manage Computer Certificates" in the dev box and find the generated certificates (under Trusted Root Cert. Authorities, and Personal Certificates).
- Open both certificates, and in the details tab, click "Copy to file" to export the certs. Choose the "Yes, export the private key" option when asked.
- Copy the cert files to the server, and double click each certificate to proceed to the import. For the Root CA cert, select the Trusted Root Cert. Authorities store as a destination for the cert to be imported).